# Download Module on NPM start

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I want to know if there is a easy way to download file before other code runs. I need file.js to be downloaded first from my server because I am requiring it in my app on different places. I know I can do something like that.

```
let file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'file.js'));
let request = http.get("http://expample.com/file.js",
    function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
});
```

But if I assume correctly, the file is written asynchronously. So when I require that file I have just empty object or error.

So what is the best way to download that file synchronously at first on npm start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get such result using npm script pre hooks.

Assuming your start-up script is called "start" , in your package.json add 
script called "prestart" in wich you want to run script that executes file downloading. and in will be automatically run when you call `npm run start`

For example:

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "prestart": "node pre-start.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

index.js:

```
const value = require('./new-file.json');
console.log(value);
```

pre-start.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');

setTimeout(function() {
    const value = {
        "one" : 1,
        "two" : 2
    };

    fs.writeFileSync('new-file.json', JSON.stringify(value));
}, 1000)
```

Here is a link to article with more detailed information:
http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html

The other way is to run your other code after file is written:

```
let file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'file.js'));
let request = http.get("http://expample.com/file.js",
    function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish',function(){
      // run your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed.